# How Converting from Gregorian to Hijri and vice versa by datepicker (vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I found it difficult to modify the code, its function is that when the user enters the date in Hijri, the code converts it to Gregorian in the Gregorian date field directly and vice versa manually. How can I change it to date picker instead of manual entry?!

```
<template>
  <div style="margin: 100px">
    <label for="hijri-date">التاريخ بالهجري:</label>

    <input
      id="hijri-date"
      v-model="hijriDate"
      @input="convertToGregorian"
      type="text"
      placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
    />

    <br />
    <label for="gregorian-date">التاريخ بالميلادي:</label>

    <input
      id="gregorian-date"
      v-model="gregorianDate"
      @input="convertToHijri"
      type="text"
      placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";
import momentHijri from "moment-hijri";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hijriDate: "",
      gregorianDate: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    convertToGregorian() {
      const hijriMoment = momentHijri(this.hijriDate, "iYYYY/iM/iD");
      const gregorianDate = hijriMoment.toDate();
      this.gregorianDate = moment(gregorianDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    },
    convertToHijri() {
      const gregorianMoment = moment(this.gregorianDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
      const hijriDate = momentHijri(gregorianMoment.toDate()).format(
        "iYYYY/iM/iD"
      );
      this.hijriDate = hijriDate;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If so, please, post the solution.